# Java idiom for "piping"

Tags: java, io, pipe

Is there a more concise/standard idiom (e.g., a JDK method) for "piping" an input to an output in Java than the following?

```
public void pipe(Reader in, Writer out) {
    CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.allocate(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    while (in.read(buf) >= 0 ) {
        out.append(buf.flip());
        buf.clear();
    }
}
```

[EDIT] Please note the `Reader` and `Writer` are *given*. The correct answer will demonstrate how to take `in` and `out` and form a pipe (preferably with no more than 1 or 2 method calls). I will accept answers where `in` and `out` are an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream` (preferably with a conversion from/to `Reader`/`Writer`). I will not accept answers where either `in` or `out` is a *subclass* of `Reader`/`InputStream` or `Writer`/`OutputStrem`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to write contents of a Java InputStream to an OutputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/) from the Apache Commons project has a number of [utilily methods](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) that do exactly what you need.

`IOUtils.copy(in, out)` will perform a buffered copy of all input to the output. If there is more than one spot in your codebase that requires `Stream` or `Reader`/`Writer` handling, using IOUtils could be a good idea.

Comment: Wow. Apache Commons is a really impressive project. They scratch all my itches before I even notice them.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [java.io.PipedInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) and [PipedOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html), or [PipedReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedReader.html)/[PipedWriter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedWriter.html) from the same package.

From the Documentation of PipedInputStream:

*A piped input stream should be connected to a piped output stream; the piped input stream then provides whatever data bytes are written to the piped output stream. Typically, data is read from a PipedInputStream  object by one thread and data is written to the corresponding PipedOutputStream  by some other thread. Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not recommended, as it may deadlock the thread. The piped input stream contains a buffer, decoupling read operations from write operations, within limits. A pipe is said to be  broken  if a thread that was providing data bytes to the connected piped output stream is no longer alive.*

Comment: Is there a way to build a PipedInputStream from a given InputStream (or Reader)?

Comment: I believe you can do something like "new PipedInputStream(theInputStreamInstance)" (i.e, "wrap InputStream with a PipedInputStream).

Comment: Sorry, leapt before I looked.  :(  Seems that there is no way to take an existing stream and turn it into a piped stream.  A PipedInputStream must be tied to a PipedOutputStream.  If you want, you can just transfers bytes from an InputStream to a PipedOutputStream that is tied to a PipedInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

The only optimization available is through FileChannels in the NIO API: [Reads](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long)), [Writes](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo(long,%20long,%20java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel)).  The JVM can optimize this call to move the data from a file to a destination Channel without first having to move the data to kernel space.  See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-zerocopy/index.html) for details.

Comment: How would I obtain a FileChannel from a Reader, Writer, InputStream, or OutputStream?