# Compiling and executing Java code using Runtime#exec()

Tags: java, runtime.exec

```
import java.io.*;

public class Auto {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac C:/HelloWorld.java");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java C:/HelloWorld > C:/out.txt");
            System.out.println("END");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This program is able to compile the 'HelloWorld.java' file, but not execute it(HelloWorld).
Could anyone please suggest me how to make it work?
Thanks in Advance! :)
Also, if the output could be able to be taken in another text file say 'output.txt'.

Comment: You don't execute the .java file.  Try `java c:/HelloWorld`.

Comment: It wasnt the fault I was interested in , I had already rectified it but posted the old erroneous code by mistake.Sorry :)

Comment: please tell me how to execute the program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your run the `java` program, you must be in your project root directory, and run `java package.to.ClassWhichContainsMainMethod`

[`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) will give you a [`Process`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) which contains an [`OutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream()) and an [`InpuStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) to the executed application.

You can redirect the [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) content to your log file.

In your case I would use this exec : [`public Process exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5C[%5C],%20java.io.File)) like this :

```
exec("java HelloWorld", null, new File("C:/"));
```

To copy data from the inputStream to the file (code stolen on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127753/java-idiom-for-piping)) :

```
public runningMethod(){
    Process p = exec("java HelloWorld", null, new File("C:/"));
    pipe(p.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream("C:/test.txt"));
}

public void pipe(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int writtenBytes;
    while((writtenBytes = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, writtenBytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andreas_D

I tried this:-
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java HelloWorld", null, new File("C:/"));

But still could not get the output in out.txt file.
I didnt know how to use getInputStream and getOutputStreams.
can u please tell me how to get the output in out.txt file?

Answer (score 3):

3 Points.

1. The JavaCompiler was introduced in Java 1.6 to allow direct compilation of Java source from within Java code.
2. ProcessBuilder (1.5+) is an easier/more robust way to launch a Process.
3. For dealing with any process, make sure you read and implement all the points of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Answer (score 0):

You do not execute a ".java" in java. You execute a class file. So change the second line to:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd c:\;java HelloWorld > C:/out.txt");
```

As for the output, instead of redirecting to a file, you might want to use the inputStream:

```
InputStream is = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd c:\;java HelloWorld").getInputStream();
```