# compile and interpret code via webservice (blackbox?)

Tags: java, python, web-services, compilation

I'd like to compile and execute Java code on a website, and automatically compare its output on a website.

The Java code should be typed in by the website-user.

I think the solution must be something like: Creating a webservice which calls a blackbox java instance and sends the output back as output for the webservice via JSON. But I don't really know how to do that and if there is a more practical solution to get the execution results of the Java code, I would love to hear about that.

I'm interested in doing things like this in Python too for example. Is there a similar solution to do that?

Hope somebody can help me to do that.

Greetings and thank you

Comment: Sounds good. Have you tried that? (e.g. via simple exec: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577736/compiling-and-executing-java-code-using-runtimeexec) - The only thing you should not do is to expose this openly on the internet because you allow people to run arbitrary code on your server which will soon be controlled by evil people. Sites like ideone.com use specialized sandboxed environments that are safe but that's nothing you can easily recreate besides bying a comercial solution.

Comment: No, I haven't tried anything yet. The problem is: I'll search for a way to to that because we wan't to create an interactive online tutorial what fitts exactly the needs of my University. And for now i'm only looking for Ideas, how it is possible to do that.