# Input and Output Stream Pipe in Java

Tags: java, input, multiple-inheritance

Does anyone have any good suggestions for creating a Pipe object in Java which *is* both an InputStream and and OutputStream since Java does not have multiple inheritance and both of the streams are abstract classes instead of interfaces?

The underlying need is to have a single object that can be passed to things which need either an InputStream or an OutputStream to pipe output from one thread to input for another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the point of this question is being missed.  If I understand you correctly, you want an object that functions like an InputStream in one thread, and an OutputStream in another to create a means of communicating between the two threads.

Perhaps one answer is to use composition instead of inheritance (which is recommended practice anyway).  Create a Pipe which contains a PipedInputStream and a PipedOutputStream connected to each other, with getInputStream() and getOutputStream() methods.

You can't directly pass the Pipe object to something needing a stream, but you can pass the return value of it's get methods to do it.

Does that work for you?

Comment: how do you add the PipedInputStream and a PipedOutputStream to the Pipe and connect them?

Answer (score 6):

java.io.PipedOutputStream and java.io.PipedInputStream look to be the classes to use for this scenario. They are designed to be used together to pipe data between threads.

If you really want some single object to pass around it would need to contain one of each of these and expose them via getters.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty common thing to do, I think. See this question.

[Easy way to write contents of a Java InputStream to an OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-ouptutstream#43164)

Comment: I know about PipedXxxStream... but I was wanting to create just one Pipe object which could be given as an InputStream to one thread and an OutputStream to another.  Was hoping I might have missed something.

Comment: Wouldn't be very hard to write something that can give you an inputstream that pipes to an outputstream, but you won't be able to extend both InputStream and OutputStream. Inheritance, bad. Composition, good.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a class which derives both from `InputStream` and `OutputStream` because these aren't interfaces and they have common methods and Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance (the compiler doesn't know whether to call `InputStream.close()` or `OutputStream.close()` if you call `close()` on your new object).

The other problem is the buffer. Java wants to allocate a static buffer for the data (which doesn't change). This means when you use the `java.io.PipedXxxStream', the writing data to it will eventually block unless you use two different threads.

So the answer from Apocalisp is correct: You must write a copy loop.

I suggest that you include Apache's commons-io in your project which contains many helper routines just for tasks like this (copy data between streams, files, strings and all combinations thereof).

Comment: You can use inner classes to achieve something similar to one class exposing both an input and output stream while sharing a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

See http://ostermiller.org/utils/CircularBuffer.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement a filter for slow connections to Servlets so basically I wrapped the servlet output stream into a QueueOutputStream which will add every byte (in small buffers), into a queue, and then output those small buffers to a 2nd output stream, so in a way this acts as input/output stream, IMHO this is better than JDK pipes which won't scale that well, basically there is too much context switching in the standard JDK implementation (per read/write), a blocking queue is just perfect for a single producer/consumer scenario:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class QueueOutputStream extends OutputStream
{
  private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE=1024;
  private static final byte[] END_SIGNAL=new byte[]{};

  private final BlockingQueue<byte[]> queue=new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
  private final byte[] buffer;

  private boolean closed=false;
  private int count=0;

  public QueueOutputStream()
  {
    this(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
  }

  public QueueOutputStream(final int bufferSize)
  {
    if(bufferSize<=0){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer size <= 0");
    }
    this.buffer=new byte[bufferSize];
  }

  private synchronized void flushBuffer()
  {
    if(count>0){
      final byte[] copy=new byte[count];
      System.arraycopy(buffer,0,copy,0,count);
      queue.offer(copy);
      count=0;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void write(final int b) throws IOException
  {
    if(closed){
      throw new IllegalStateException("Stream is closed");
    }
    if(count>=buffer.length){
      flushBuffer();
    }
    buffer[count++]=(byte)b;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void write(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len) throws IOException
  {
    super.write(b,off,len);
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void close() throws IOException
  {
    flushBuffer();
    queue.offer(END_SIGNAL);
    closed=true;
  }

  public Future<Void> asyncSendToOutputStream(final ExecutorService executor, final OutputStream outputStream)
  {
    return executor.submit(
            new Callable<Void>()
            {
              @Override
              public Void call() throws Exception
              {
                try{
                  byte[] buffer=queue.take();
                  while(buffer!=END_SIGNAL){
                    outputStream.write(buffer);
                    buffer=queue.take();
                  }
                  outputStream.flush();
                } catch(Exception e){
                  close();
                  throw e;
                } finally{
                  outputStream.close();
                }
                return null;
              }
            }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Better to use Pipe or ArrayBlockingQueue, I recommend you not to use PipedInput/OutputStream as they have a bad practice even you can see in the link below that they have asked to be deprecated as it causes many issues.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223048

For the BlockingQueue and Pipe here a simple example of that

**Pipe:**

```
Pipe pipe = Pipe.open();
Pipe.SinkChannel sinkChannel = pipe.sink();
String newData = "New String to write to file..." + System.currentTimeMillis();

ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
buf.clear();
buf.put(newData.getBytes());

buf.flip();

while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
    sinkChannel.write(buf);
}
Pipe.SourceChannel sourceChannel = pipe.source();
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);

int bytesRead = inChannel.read(buf);
```

Reference: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/pipe.html

**BlockingQueue:**

```
//Shared class used by threads
public class Buffer {
    // ArrayBlockingQueue
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1);

    public void get() {
        // retrieve from ArrayBlockingQueue
        try {
            System.out.println("Consumer received - " + blockingQueue.take());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void put(int data) {
        try {
            // putting in ArrayBlockingQueue
            blockingQueue.put(data);
            System.out.println("Producer produced - " + data);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Starting two threads
        ExecutorService executorService = null;
        try {
            Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
            executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
            executorService.execute(new Producer(buffer));
            executorService.execute(new Consumer(buffer));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(executorService != null) {
                executorService.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private Buffer buffer;

    public Consumer(Buffer buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                buffer.get();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Producer implements Runnable {
    private Buffer buffer;

    public Producer(Buffer buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int data = random.nextInt(1000);
            buffer.put(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://github.com/kishanjavatrainer/ArrayBlockingQueueDemo/tree/master/ArrayBlockingQueueDemo