# How to use linux commands involving ">" through runTime.exec()

Tags: java, linux, inputstream, ubuntu-12.04

I'm new to Java. I want to use a command

```
"ps -e > /home/root/workspace/MyProject/ProcessList.txt"
```

with runTime.exec();

On searching through the web, I came to know that runTime.exec() doesn't support pipes or redirecting. Please let me know how can I execute this command with my Java code. Please give exact answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes and redirection are features provided by the shell. The easy (and dirty) solution is to spawn the command inside a shell: `"/bin/sh -c 'ps -e > /home/root/workspace/MyProject/ProcessList.txt'"`.

Edit: I had forgotten that the default `StringTokenizer` does not work with quoted strings. Provide arguments as an array of strings.

```
String[] args = {
    "/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    "ps -e > /home/root/workspace/MyProject/ProcessList.txt"
};
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime(args);
```

Comment: so you're saying it should be something like:

    run.exec("/bin/sh -c 'ps -e > /home/root/workspace/MyProject/ProcessList.txt'"); ????

Comment: @IngilaEjaz Exactly. Edited to clarify.

Comment: @IngilaEjaz You have access rights to create the file? The directory `/home/root/workspace/MyProject` already exists?

Comment: @IngilaEjaz I had forgotten that the default StringTokenizer does not work with quoted strings. See my edit.

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote. Still no luck :'( it says no such file :(

Comment: @IngilaEjaz it means you have to create the `/home/root/workspace/MyProject`directory first.

Comment: It is already created MyProject is where I have that run.exec() method defined :(

Comment: Thanks so much kmkaplan :) I had been trying to do it for like 2 days :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at this question: [Input and Output Stream Pipe in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364936/input-and-output-stream-pipe-in-java)

Otherwise, if you know you are on a platform that supports the bourne shell (`sh`), you could add that to the command to run the original command in that shell:

`"sh -c 'ps -e > /home/root/workspace/MyProject/ProcessList.txt'"`