# Generate chart with JFreeChart and Apache PDFBOX

Tags: jfreechart, pdfbox

I need to generate charts using [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) and then export them to PDF using [Apache PDFBOX](http://pdfbox.apache.org/). I don't want to use iText as it cannot be used in proprietary software.

I searched all over Google, but no luck! Has anyone done it?

Answer (score 5):

Copy the `OutputStream` from your chosen `writeChartAs*()` method in [`ChartUtilities`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtilities.html) to the `InputStream` used to create a `PDXObjectImage` in [`AddImageToPDF`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddImageToPDF.java). A typical `copyStream()` implementation is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574837/connecting-an-input-stream-to-an-outputstream/1574857#1574857).

Addendum: Alternatively, use piped streams to copy from output to input, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443878/redirecting-system-out-to-jtextpane/4444677#4444677) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484119/why-doesnt-more-java-code-use-pipedinputstream-pipedoutputstream).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports). They are a bit heavy, but working good.

Comment: But JasperReports internally use iText to generate PDF files. Due to some requirements I need to use Apache PDFBOX **ONLY**.

Comment: So, than what is the problem actually? You generate an image stream from JFreeChart and then include it into the PDF. Here http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/cookbook.html there is a AddImageToPDF sample.

Comment: The [AddImageToPDF](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddImageToPDF.html) creates PDF from a file instead of a stream. And due to some restrictions I cannot save the chart image on server. I need something which will take chart image as stream and then output PDF also as stream.