# Add BufferedImage to PDFBox document

Tags: java, jfreechart, bufferedimage, pdfbox

In my current project, I try to add a `BufferedImage` to a PDFBox document. More specificly, I use an image from a `JFreeChart`. My code looks like this:

```
public void exportToPDF(JFreeChart chart, String filePath){
    PDDocument doc = null;
    PDPage page = null;
    PDXObjectImage ximage = null;

    try {
        doc = new PDDocument();
        page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);
        PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        BufferedImage image = chart.createBufferedImage(300, 300);
        ximage = new PDJpeg(doc, image);
        content.drawImage(ximage, 20, 20);
        content.close();
    } catch(IOException ie) {
    }
    doc.save(filePath);
    doc.close();
}
```

The document gets created; I can add text, but I get an error stating the the image does not have enough information to be shown.

Any clue to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error message is displayed in the generated pdf file, I should have been clear on that. When i open the file it dislays all text as it should but instead of an image i get a message "Unsufficient data to display image". Im more or less green when it comes to siplaying images so any ideas are welcomed

Comment: This might be this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2026 It will be fixed in 1.8.5. Or download a snapshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for helping me out trashgod. Spent last night and a few hours today beeing confused about PipedIn/OutStreams. Can´t figure it out. However, i got it to work. Turns out it wasn´t very difficult at all.

```
public void exportToPDF(JFreeChart chart, String filePath){
    PDDocument doc = null;
    PDPage page = null;
    PDXObjectImage ximage = null;
    try {
        doc = new PDDocument();
        page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);
        PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

        //create a new outStream
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(out, chart, 300, 300);//write to outstream
        //create a new inputstream
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        ximage = new PDJpeg(doc, in);
        content.drawImage(ximage, 5, 300);
        content.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ie){
        //handle exception
    }
    //save and close
    doc.save(filePath);
    doc.close();
}
```

I´m sure this can be done better but it works.

Answer (score 5):

There is an easy way to insert a JFreeChart into a pdf with pdfbox:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = source.getChart().createBufferedImage(source.getWidth(),
        source.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, null);
PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDJpeg(doc, bufferedImage);
```

Without any stream ;)

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for back then. Great!

Answer (score 3):

Two things stand out:

- Do not swallow exceptions.
- Do use [`ChartUtilities`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtilities.html) to render the image in a suitable format, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041347/generate-chart-with-jfreechart-and-apache-pdfbox/7042707#7042707).

Comment: So i looked at what you said, i can get an outputStream by using: OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); and then:  ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(out, chart, 300, 300);  however, i can´t figure out how to turn this into an inputstream.

Comment: To move data from an `OutputStream` to an `InputStream` use piped streams, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443878/redirecting-system-out-to-jtextpane/4444677#4444677) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484119/why-doesnt-more-java-code-use-pipedinputstream-pipedoutputstream).

Comment: Also, you can just save the image as a file or cache its byte array.  Also consider the `PNG` v `JPG` [tradeoff](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/png-vs-jpg).