# Place an image on a PDF file using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, pdfbox

I've manged  to place text into a pdf file using Javafx and PDFbox from Apache. Now I am trying to place an image from taking a screen shot of a scene, to the pdf document.

```
    WritableImage snapshot = quotes.getScene().snapshot(null);
    PDDocument doc = null;
    PDPage page = null;
    PDXObjectImage ximg = null;
    BufferedImage bufferedImg = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null);

   try{
       doc = new PDDocument();
       page = new PDPage();


       doc.addPage(page);
       PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);


      /* ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());*/

      ximg = new PDJpeg(doc, bufferedImg);
      //ximg = new PDJpeg(doc, in);
      content.drawImage(ximg, 100, 100);

      content.close();
      doc.save("PDFWithText.pdf");
      doc.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    }
```

When I use the InputStream and OutputStream classes, the document is created but when I open it, Adobe along with other programs gives me an error saying Acrobat cannot display page correctly. When I use the BufferedImage class instead that is commented out in the above code, the document is simple not created and I don't know why.

*NOTE*

This is a follow-up question to [Taking a screenshot of a scene or a portion of a scene in JavaFx 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024498/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-scene-or-a-portion-of-a-scene-in-javafx-2-2/), but specific to the pdf creation portion rather than the node snapshot portion.

Comment: This might be this bug: http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2026 It will be fixed in 1.8.5. Or download a snapshot.

Answer (score 4):

*This is not an actual a solution (because the code provided does not work), instead it is a documentation of my attempts to solve the problem*

I spent some time trying to solve this and was unable to.  I have included the sample code for my solution as it provides an SSCCE and approach which may help other people trying to solve this problem.

The two approaches I tried were:

1. Taking a BufferedImage output by the JavaFX method SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage and using that as input to the pdfbox api.

   This approach did not work because the BufferedImage created by SwingFXUtils is encoded with a SampleModel that is incompatible with that required by the pdfbox api.
2. Creating a Jpeg stream (using ImageIO) out of the BufferedImage output by the JavaFX method SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage and using that as input to the pdfbox api.

   This approach did not work.  Perhaps the reason for the failure was that ImageIO creates pink tinted (i.e. incorrectly encoded) jpegs from the BufferedImage created by SwingFXUtils.  This may a bug in ImageIO.  Additionally there may be bugs in how I am adding the result image to the jpeg using pdfbox.

*Recommendation*

There are numerous other apis for creating PDF files from JavaFX.  Rather than continuing to troubleshoot integration of images output from JavaFX with pdfbox, I suggest trying any of the other apis to perform the task of creating a pdf file (a google search will reveal them).

*Executable Sample Code*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDJpeg;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

// #### THIS CODE CURRENTLY DOES NOT FUNCTION CORRECTLY - SEE INLINE COMMENTS IN THE CODE TO UNDERSTAND WHY ####
//
// Demonstrates converting a JavaFX SceneGraph to a pdf (just as a bitmapped image, not as vector graphics).
//   1. creating a snapshot of a JavaFX node.
//   2. creating a pdf from the snapshot (using apache pdfbox http://pdfbox.apache.org/).
//   3. saving the pdf to a file.
//   4. opening the saved pdf in a web browser so the web browser can trigger showing
//      the pdf in an appropriate pdf viewer (if the user has such a viewer installed).
public class PdfWithImageCreator extends Application {
    // icon courtesy of http://www.aha-soft.com/ not for commercial use (free for non-commercial use).
    private static final String imageURL =
            "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aha-soft/free-global-security/512/Global-Network-icon.png";

    private static final String PDF_PATH =
            Paths.get("exported.pdf").toAbsolutePath().toString();

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox layout = new VBox(20);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(
            new Image(imageURL)
        );

        Button export = new Button("Export");
        export.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                exportToPDF(layout, PDF_PATH);
            }
        });

        layout.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20px;");
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        layout.getChildren().setAll(
            export,
            imageView
        );

        stage.setScene(
            new Scene(
                new Group(
                    layout
                )
            )
        );

        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Snapshots the provided node.
     * Encodes the snapshot in a pdf.
     * Saves the pdf to the provided file path.
     * Opens the pdf in the default system web browser.
     *
     * @param node the node for which the snapshot is to be taken.
     * @param filePath the path where the pdf is to be saved.
     */
    private void exportToPDF(Node node, String filePath){
        PDDocument doc = null;
        PDPage page = null;
        PDPageContentStream content = null;
        PDXObjectImage ximage = null;

        try {
            // snapshot the node and convert it to an awt buffered image.
            Image fxImage = node.snapshot(null, null);
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(fxImage, null);

            // create a pdf containing the snapshot image.
            doc = new PDDocument();
            page = new PDPage();
            doc.addPage(page);

            content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

            // alternate path A => try to create a PDJpeg from a jpegInputStream.
            ximage = createPDJpegFromJpegStream(doc, bufferedImage);

            // alternate path B => try to create a PDJpeg from directly from a BufferedImage directly.
            // ximage = createPDJpegFromBufferedImage(doc, bufferedImage);

            content.drawImage(ximage, 0, 0);
            content.close();

            // save the created image to disk.
            doc.save(filePath);

            System.out.println("Exported PDF to: " + filePath);

            // show the generated pdf in a web browser.
            // (if the browser is pdf enabled, this will display the pdf in the web browser).
            getHostServices().showDocument(filePath);
        } catch(IOException | COSVisitorException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (content != null) { content.close(); }
                if (doc     != null) { doc.close(); }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // #### THIS METHOD DOES NOT FUNCTION AS EXPECTED
    // alternate path => try to create a PDJpeg from a jpegInputStream.
    // when using a jpeg stream this doesn't work, the created pdf is not well formed and
    // you end up with adobe pdf reader running out of memory trying to read the resultant pdf.
    // Also outputs a weird message that I currently don't understand =>
    //    INFO: About to return NULL from unhandled branch. filter = COSName{DCTDecode}
    private PDXObjectImage createPDJpegFromJpegStream(PDDocument doc, BufferedImage bufferedImage) throws IOException {
        // provide the buffered image data as input to a jpeg input stream.
        ByteArrayOutputStream jpegOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageOutputStream jpegImageOutputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(jpegOutputStream);
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg", jpegImageOutputStream);
        InputStream jpegInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                Arrays.copyOf(jpegOutputStream.toByteArray(), jpegOutputStream.size())
        );

        // output created jpg file for debugging purposes
        // => when you view it is pink due to (I believe) an ImageIO bug.
        // you can see how the resultant image is pink by opening the image file named in system.out in any image viewer.
        // this improper encoding of the jpeg data may be why the subsequent use of it to generate a pdf
        // will generate a an invalid pdf.
        File file = new File("output.jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(Arrays.copyOf(jpegOutputStream.toByteArray(), jpegOutputStream.size()));
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

        return new PDJpeg(doc, jpegInputStream);
    }

    // #### THIS METHOD DOES NOT FUNCTION AS EXPECTED
    // alternate path => try to create a PDJpeg from directly from a BufferedImage directly, get the following exception:
    // Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Raster IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 552 height = 616 #Bands = 1 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0 is incompatible with ColorModel ColorModel: #pixelBits = 8 numComponents = 1 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@125fe1b6 transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false
    //    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:630)
    // Browsing the awt PDJpeg and awt code it appears that the BufferedImage returned by JavaFX uses a
    // SinglePixelPackedSampleModel, but PDJpeg required the buffered image to use a ComponentColorModel
    // and the two are incompatible.  So the bufferedimage needs to be re-encoded to a compatible
    // raster format that utilizes a SampleModel (i.e. a ComponentColorModel) that is acceptable by PDJpeg.
    //
    private PDXObjectImage createPDJpegFromBufferedImage(PDDocument doc, BufferedImage bufferedImage) throws IOException {
        return new PDJpeg(doc, bufferedImage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: I recently ran across the ImageIO jpg bug, where things have a purple tint.  There is a little more information here (account required) https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23502.  If there is another image format the PDF library supports, you might try that.  In my project, I switched to PNG, and the images looked fine.  But I wasn't dealing with PDF's...

Comment: Yes PNG did look better however the pdf library i'm using doesn't seem to support it. I've managed to figure out the purple tint problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the Snapshot into PDF by converting the image to PNG and writing it to an Outputstream first and reading the converted PNG from outputstream to the BufferedImage.

The final BufferedImage renders fine in the PDJpeg without any issues.

Here is my code.

```
public static BufferedImage generate_png_from_container(Node node) {
        SnapshotParameters param = new SnapshotParameters();
        param.setDepthBuffer(true);
        WritableImage snapshot = node.snapshot(param, null);
        BufferedImage tempImg = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null);
        BufferedImage img = null;
        byte[] imageInByte;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(tempImg, "png", baos);
            baos.flush();
            imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
            img = ImageIO.read(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       //the final image sent to the PDJpeg
       return img;
}
```