# How to convert animation to video format?

Tags: animation, video, javafx-2

I have application which simply is an animation (some circles moving around).

I want to know how can I save this animation as video like MP4?

OR is it possible to record(capture) things which happen inside a node and save it as video format?

Comment: You can also use this tool http://www.vibot.site/ I think there is also an API support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build-in functionality for that.

1. If you just want to record how your application run there are several tools for that. E.g [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/)
2. If you want to create your own video programmatically you need to use some 3rd party software (or write one), which allows to encode set of images to video. E.g. [Xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/). Here you can find how to take screenshots in JavaFX: [Taking a screenshot of a scene or a portion of a scene in JavaFx 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024498/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-scene-or-a-portion-of-a-scene-in-javafx-2-2)

Comment: So, imagine I want to create a video editing application, I can not save my result video?

Comment: Of course you can, it's software -- everything is possible, just you have to try harder for some tasks. Updated an answer.