# Add BufferedImage to PDFBox 2.0 document

Tags: java, jfreechart, bufferedimage, pdfbox

First time poster, bear with me...

I have two questions.  First, I want to know how to add an image to a PDFBox 2.0 document using a BufferedImage.  The question has been asked here: [Add BufferedImage to PDFBox document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055485/add-bufferedimage-to-pdfbox-document)

PDFBox has since excluded the PDJpeg class and the xobject section as a whole.

Second, if someone has already asked this question and it has been answered, but the answer is deprecated; what's the best way to update/the best way to connect these two questions?  (I don't have any points so I can't comment).

Comment: Thank you for citing the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055485/add-bufferedimage-to-pdfbox-document); [*Migration to PDFBox 2.0.0: Working with Images*](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html) may help; if you get something working, please add an answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055485/add-bufferedimage-to-pdfbox-document).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> PDFBox has since excluded the PDJpeg class and the xobject section as a whole.

There indeed has been a lot of refactoring (and re-refactoring and re-re-refactoring etc) during the development of version 2, and this refactoring often goes beyond mere package changes. And quite often it is not obvious where some functionality is now.

But a basic functionality like *adding a `BufferedImage` to a document* can be counted on not being lost.

There now is the [JPEGFactory](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/2.0.0/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/JPEGFactory.java) which provides methods to create image XObjects from a `BufferedImage`, in particular:

```
/**
 * Creates a new JPEG Image XObject from a Buffered Image.
 * @param document the document where the image will be created
 * @param image the buffered image to embed
 * @return a new Image XObject
 * @throws IOException if the JPEG data cannot be written
 */
public static PDImageXObject createFromImage(PDDocument document, BufferedImage image)

/**
 * Creates a new JPEG Image XObject from a Buffered Image and a given quality.
 * The image will be created at 72 DPI.
 * @param document the document where the image will be created
 * @param image the buffered image to embed
 * @param quality the desired JPEG compression quality
 * @return a new Image XObject
 * @throws IOException if the JPEG data cannot be written
 */
public static PDImageXObject createFromImage(PDDocument document, BufferedImage image, float quality)

/**
 * Creates a new JPEG Image XObject from a Buffered Image, a given quality and DPI.
 * @param document the document where the image will be created
 * @param image the buffered image to embed
 * @param quality the desired JPEG compression quality
 * @param dpi the desired DPI (resolution) of the JPEG
 * @return a new Image XObject
 * @throws IOException if the JPEG data cannot be written
 */
public static PDImageXObject createFromImage(PDDocument document, BufferedImage image, float quality, int dpi)
```

Comment: Thank you much!  If anyone stumbles on this and is wondering about the PNG version: 
PDImageXObject pdImage= LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc, bufferedImage);