# How to show Buffered Image on PDF?

Tags: java, pdfbox, bufferedimage

So basically I want to show a BufferedImage on a PDF-Document using Java and PDFBox.
There was a way using this method ([Add BufferedImage to PDFBox 2.0 document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367622/add-bufferedimage-to-pdfbox-2-0-document)) but it seems to be deprecated.
Is there any new way to show a BufferedImage on a PDocument?

Comment: Where do you see deprecation of the methods I referenced in my answer to the question you linked?

Comment: please take a look into this psot if its helpfull
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055485/add-bufferedimage-to-pdfbox-document

Comment: Try also `LosslessFactory.createFromImage(PDDocument document, BufferedImage image)` if your image is something with sharp edges. If your image is a photograph, then use the `JPEGFactory` methods. (Another case is black/white images but I'm skipping that one)

Comment: the "createFromImage()" method doesnt exist anymore

Comment: Thank you Tilman Hausherr your answer worked for me :)

Comment: I'm wondering why it didn't work the first time, i.e. why did you think that it "doesnt exist anymore"?

Comment: because the "createFromImage()" method doesnt belong or exist in the PDImageXObject class since like 2017. It seems to be refactored and is now in the LossLessFactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also `LosslessFactory.createFromImage(PDDocument document, BufferedImage image)` if your image is something with sharp edges. If your image is a photograph, then use the `JPEGFactory` methods.