# Building a process pipe with ProcessBuilder in Java 7

Tags: java, pipe, processbuilder

I've been trying to figure out how to pipe a few processes in Java using the new `ProcessBuilder`. I can't find a suitable example of what I want to do and when I try to do it myself the process just hangs. I would appreciate a very simple example of some code that runs the equivalent of `cat test.txt | wc`, but not through a shell.

--Update--

OK, just to clarify. I know there are ways to simulate a pipe by reading and writing streams. I'm wondering if that's done in some automatic way by the [redirectInput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectInput%28%29) and [redirectOutput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput%28%29) methods introduced in Java 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a pipe in this case.

```
"grep bla test.txt"
```

however assuming you need a pipe, you need to use a shell like bash

```
"/bin/bash", "-c", "grep foo text.txt | grep bar"
```

Comment: I am trying to use the redirectInput and redirectOutput methods in the ProcessBuilder to simulate a pipe.

Comment: As far as I can see you can only redirect to a file this way and you cannot add your own types.  How exactly are you trying to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible. Do you have any idea what the PIPE ([link]http://www.fxfrog.com/docs_www/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html#PIPE) type is for? I imagined that it's possible to redirect the output to be the input of another process.

Comment: The Javadoc states this is `Indicates that subprocess I/O will be connected to the current Java process over a pipe.` You have to read/write the stream in the current Java process. i.e. the PIPE is between the process you run and the Java process, not two processes you are running.

Comment: Thank you. I was beginning to realize that it wasn't what I supposed it is.

Comment: I was using a shell, but I wanted to use a more Java-ish way of constructing the pipe. I'm doing it now the way Aaron Digulla suggested. I copied this (http://blog.bensmann.com/piping-between-processes) implementation, works like a charm.

Comment: It's very disappointing that neither the java API nor Apache commons provide a method to chain processes together into a pipeline. I guess not enough people appreciate the elegance of pipelines

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat it's not in the API but you can pass a pipeline of processes to a shell.

Comment: Yeah. I was hoping that java could serve as the glue code so that you could so more creative things. Somehow I also don't trust shells as robust, production-reliable constructs for IPC. I've found some mysterious lack of stdout output when my process was running fine.

Answer (score 3):

Start a child thread for each `Input-`/`OutputStream` pair with a simple copy loop in `run()`.