# configure Maven Shade minimizeJar to include class files

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am trying to minimize the UberJar's size by using `Maven Shade Plugin`'s  `minimizeJar`. It looks like `minimizeJar` only includes classes that are statically imported in the code (I suspect this because I see `LogFactory.class` in uber jar at `org\apache\commons\logging\` but no classes of the `impl` package are included, hence throwing `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl` when I run the uber-jar).

Is there any way I can tell Maven's Shade plugin to include specified packages into the final jar no matter what the `minimizeJar` suggests?

Here the pom snippet of what I am trying:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>commons-logging:commons-logging</artifact>
                            <includes>
                                <include>org/apache/commons/logging/**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </filter>    
                    </filters>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>com.myproject.Main</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>                            
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: `org/apache/commons/logging/**` only matches directories, you maybe want to match all files. Use `org/apache/commons/logging/**/*` instead.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I tried `...logging/**` , `...logging/**/*`, `...logging/**/*.*` but none worked. I guess the problem is includes are included first then minimizeJar ignores everything else and bundles the jar as it thinks is suitable.

Answer (score 16):

This functionality has been added to version 1.6 of the maven-shade-plugin (just released). minimizeJar will now not remove classes that have been specifically included with filters. Note that including some of an artifact's classes in a filter will exclude non-specified classes for that artifact, so be sure to include all the classes that you need.

Here's an example plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>    
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>                        
            <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>    
                <filters> 
                    <filter>
                       <artifact>log4j:log4j</artifact>
                       <includes>
                           <include>**</include>
                       </includes>
                    </filter> 
                    <filter>
                       <artifact>commons-logging:commons-logging</artifact>
                       <includes>
                           <include>**</include>
                       </includes>
                    </filter>                      
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The bottom-level `<include>**</include>` didn't work for me. It seems to include a lot of things from other packages too. Instead I had to use `<include>org/apache/logging/log4j/**</include> <include>Log4j-*</include>`

Comment: Still not work with version 3.2.4

Answer (score 13):

I am using the 2.0 version of the Maven Shade Plugin and still I am not able to include classes after "minimizing" the JAR.

As a workaround the only thing that comes to my mind is to create references to the needed classes to avoid the minimization code to get rid of them. ie:

```
/*
 * This block prevents the Maven Shade plugin to remove the specified classes
 */
static {
    @SuppressWarnings ("unused") Class<?>[] classes = new Class<?>[] {
        JButton.class,
        JMenu.class,
        JMenuBar.class,
        JMenuItem.class
    };
}
```

I hope Maven developers implement a way to handle this situation (which I guess is very common).

Comment: 2022, still have to do this for log4j. log4j in general has so many config issues