# Minimize an Uber Jar correctly, Using Shade-Plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, executable-jar

I am using the Maven-Shade-Plugin to create a runnable Uber-jar.
According to the last frame on [this page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html), the size of the jar can be minimized by using:

```
<configuration>
      <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
</configuration>
```

But this feature does not take into consideration the classes that are declared in the log4j.properties file. Hence, e.g. `org.apache.log4j.appender.TimeAndSizeRollingAppender` is not included in the Uber-jar, even though it’s declared in the log4j.properties file.

I believe I will face the same problem with Spring. If my code only refers to interface A and my Spring file contains an instantiation of class B that implements A, then B might not be added to the jar, since it’s not in the code.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Alsmot, but not quite, a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698814/configure-maven-shade-minimizejar-to-include-class-files

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This functionality has been added to version 1.6 of the maven-shade-plugin (just released). minimizeJar will now not remove classes that have been specifically included with filters. Note that including some of an artifact's classes in a filter will exclude non-specified classes for that artifact, so be sure to include all the classes that you need.

Here's an example plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>    
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>                        
            <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>    
                <filters> 
                    <filter>
                       <artifact>log4j:log4j</artifact>
                       <includes>
                           <include>**</include>
                       </includes>
                    </filter> 
                    <filter>
                       <artifact>commons-logging:commons-logging</artifact>
                       <includes>
                           <include>**</include>
                       </includes>
                    </filter>                      
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

To only include specific classes, add them as includes using path slashes in the class name in a filter (again, non-included classes will be automatically excluded).

```
<filter>
  <artifact>org.yourorg:your-artifact</artifact>
  <includes>
    <include>org/yourorg/yourartifact/api/*</include>
    <include>org/yourorg/yourartifact/util/*</include>
  </includes>
</filter>
```

Comment: A copy of the Maven documentation.

Comment: Can you support "always keep specific classes" option?
For instance, a configuration lists particular classes/masks to keep, and maven-shade-plugin automatically calculates unused classes?

Comment: @VladimirSitnikov Edited answer, I believe the includes filter at the bottom should work to include specific classes.

Comment: >again, non-included classes will be automatically excluded

I do not want to manually figure out all the classes I need to include.

Comment: I do not want to manually figure out all the classes I need to include.
For instance, jarjar ant plugin automatically scans for the used classes and all you need to do is to specify Main class

Comment: maven-shade-plugin already scans a project for dependencies and automatically includes then when using `<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>`. However, when your code or a depdendency uses dynamic class loading, there's no way for maven-shade-plugin to detect a dependency on the dynamically loaded classes, so you **have to** manually include those dependencies using filter includes as demonstrated here. If you don't want to do this, use `<minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>` and just deal with the larger shaded jar. Those are your choices.

Comment: In this case Proguard is the way to go... It can handle things when a depdendency uses dynamic class loading.

Comment: Does Proguard have a runtime profile aspect to gather details of which classes are actually accessed, that it uses to feed the jar-minification-generation-thingie?