# Runnable jar in Maven and how to work with dependencies and manifest

Tags: java, maven

When I run Maven from Eclipse and I generate a JAR, I need to run the JAR in that way from command line, once released:

```
java -classpath [long list of dependencies] uk.co.superzoom.App
```

Is it the best way of releasing a JAR or should i change the pom.xml in order to be able to run the JAR in that way:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

If the second case, two changes would be needed:

1) Add to the manifest the infromation about the main class in order to create a runnable JAR

```
Main-Class: uk.co.superzoom.App
```

2) Add all the dependencies automatically, without having to write the long list from command line every time (at the moment they are only visible from Eclipse, but from command line I need to add the long list).

How can I implement the steps (1) and (2) in my pom.xml. Can you provide any example of this?

Comment: Use the maven shade plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Use Maven-Shade-Plugin.

From [the plugin's page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/):

> This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an uber-jar, including its dependencies and to shade - i.e. rename - the packages of some of the dependencies.

The plugin bundles all the dependencies into a runable jar file. It also lets you minimize the size of the jar file by using the following code:

```
<configuration>
  <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
</configuration>
```

See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8817257/416300) for some information regarding minimization.