# User class threw exception: scala.ScalaReflectionException: classxyxz

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am hitting this error and unable to find any resolution so far. using Intellj Intellj community version 2019.2.3 and maven for bulid

Scenario :

1. Module A has  A,B,C css class definition files defining the schema for the datasets
2. Module B has dependency on Module A with dependency defined in the POM
3. Module B is the main Module .  I am getting a this error

> User class threw exception: scala.ScalaReflectionException: class "C"
> in JavaMirror with
> org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader@40021799 of type class
> org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader with classpath
> file:/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1610888522323_13133/container_e03_1610888522323_13133_01_000001/**app**.jar]
> and parent being sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@306a30c7 of type
> class sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader with classpath

Code is val temp:

```
Dataset[A] = getFoo() 
Val slimDataset: Dataset[C] = temp.Select($"ColA",$"colN").as[C]
```

This line is throwing an exception saying unable to load the file.   I opened Module `A.jar` which has Classes `A` and `B` from  `Module B` but `C` is missing.

Any thoughts on why Intellj is not including all the libraries (in this case class `C` from `Module B`)?

Comment: I figured minimize jar option is excluding some of the class files from the Module B above.  <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar> . It seems we can mention filters in this config section to tell to maven not to exclude the class files.  .  Is it the artifiact Id  ? Any pointers on how to use thee filers to include module please ?

Comment: I came across this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817257/minimize-an-uber-jar-correctly-using-shade-plugin , but  i am getting security exception in the manifest when i tired to follow the suggestion mentioned in the above thread.  I am not able to ask on that thread as I dont have enough reputation points :( . Any help on this will be appreciated