# Maven - How to compile only used classes?

Tags: java, maven

**Hey there!**
I know this question has probably been asked countless times, but I have been looking online for quite a while and I could not find a real solution.

I am working on a **project B**, that uses a **project A** as **dependency** like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now, **project A** has quite a lot of classes and I would like to **compile only the ones project B actually uses**, not the whole bunch.

Is there a way of doing that? If so, can you point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

I should also mention that I **do not** want to **manually insert** every class used: I am searching for a more **automatic solution**.

Comment: declaring a dependency on Project A does not do anything involving compilation.  all that means is that Project B will use the Project A jar when compiling Project B.

Comment: adding to @jtahlborn answer, the classes in the jar dependency are expected to be compiled. If you want to compile something it should be in your project, not in dependencies.

Comment: If what you really mean is that you want the application you deliver to only include the needed classes from the dependency, look at [ProGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/proguard)

Comment: The Maven shade plugin also allows you to minimize the executable JAR.

Comment: @TimMoore can you explain more on that? I tried using ProGuard, but I did not have any luck.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I did not know you could do that with shade, how would I do that?

Comment: @Alexander https://stackoverflow.com/q/8817257/927493

Comment: Awesome, thank you :)