# save email attachment

Tags: java, email, attachment, pgp

can anyone suggest me how to save email attachment using Java?
It is encrypted file (PGP). I need to save it and use for decryption. I use this code:

```
String host = "mail.foxbox.lt";
String user = "user";
String password = "pass";
Properties properties = System.getProperties();

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
store.connect(host, user, password);
Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Message[] message = folder.getMessages();
for (int a = message.length-1; a < message.length; a++) {
     Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message[a].getContent();
     for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
          BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
          InputStream stream = bodyPart.getInputStream();
          if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equals(bodyPart.getDisposition())) {
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
               FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("AAA001.txt.pgp");
               BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

               int y;
               while ((y = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    out.write(y);
               }
               stream.close();
               out.close();
          }
     }
     System.out.println();
}
folder.close(true);
store.close();
```

But it works only for text files (strings). in my case it changes .pgp file and gives me decryption error.
How do I save file without any stream?
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you use `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`. These are intended to use with character streams. The will convert the byte sequence that you read from the attachment to Unicode character codepoints (`char` type) using the default platform encoding and vice versa. During the encoding or decoding process, unmappable characters may be replaced or left out from the stream.

You have to use plain `InputStream` for reading the attachment and `FileOutputStream` for writing to the file:

```
InputStream stream = bodyPart.getInputStream();
if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equals(bodyPart.getDisposition())) {
    FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream("AAA001.txt.pgp");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        fstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    fstream.close();
}
stream.close();
```

There are other methods for copying the contents of an `InputStream` to a `OutputStream`, see [this question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream).

Comment: THANK YOU :) Quick answer + clear explanation + code! Perfect!

Comment: @user1164545 you liked the answer? So please upvote and mark as correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String host = "host";
String user = "user";
String password = "pass";
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
store.connect(host, user, password);
Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
Message[] message = folder.getMessages();
for (int a = message.length-1; a < message.length; a++) {
        Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message[a].getContent();    
  for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
      BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);           
      InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();
      File f = new File("/tmp/" + bodyPart.getFileName());
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
      byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
      int bytesRead;
      while((bytesRead = is.read(buf))!=-1) {
          fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
      }
      fos.close();
      attachments.add(f);
    }
  }
  folder.close(true);
  store.close();
 }
```