# Android - Whats the most efficient way to read an inputstream and save as file?

Tags: java, android

I currently use the following to read a bluetooth inputstream and save it as a file. It works well with small files but then with larger files its creating a large byte array first. Whats the most efficient way of doing this AND making sure that it reads the only the length specified, no more, no less?

```
    public void getAndWrite(InputStream is, long length, String filename)
            throws IOException {

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
                && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read stream ");
        }

        // Write the byte array to file
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = mContext.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Problem finding internal storage", e);
        }
        try {
            fos.write(bytes);
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Problem writing file", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will cause you heap problems, as you are trying to read the whole thing into memory. Open your `FileOutputStream` and write to it as you read, in larger chunks than ~1K. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43163/115145

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int bufferSize = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int remaining = length;
int read = 0;
while (remaining > 0 
       && (read = in.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(remaining, bufferSize))) >= 0) {
   out.write(buffer, 0, read);
   remaining -= read;
}
```

Note that the above makes sure you  don't write more that length bytes. But it doesn't make sure you write exactly length bytes. I don't see how you could do this without reading length bytes in memory, or reading length bytes and writing to a temp file, then writing the temp file to the final destination.

Comment: Thanks, it works a treat without the heap problems I was running into.