# Android - Store inputstream in file

Tags: android, input, stream

I am retrieveing an XML feed from a url and then parsing it. What I need to do is also store that internally to the phone so that when there is no internet connection it can parse the saved option rather than the live one.

The problem I am facing is that I can create the url object, use getInputStream to get the contents, but it will not let me save it.

```
URL url = null;
InputStream inputStreamReader = null;
XmlPullParser xpp = null;

url = new URL("http://*********");
inputStreamReader = getInputStream(url);

ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFileAppeal.srl"));

//--------------------------------------------------------
//This line is where it is erroring.
//--------------------------------------------------------
out.writeObject( inputStreamReader );
//--------------------------------------------------------
out.close();
```

Any ideas how I can go about saving the input stream so I can load it later.

Cheers

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Here it is, input is your `inputStream`. Then use same File (name) and `FileInputStream` to read the data in future.

```
try {
    File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "cacheFileAppeal.srl");
    try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
        int read;

        while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        output.flush();
    }
} finally {
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: Nesting try blocks though?

Comment: Exception can happen anytime if so you will leak system resources.

Comment: The "input" variable is an instance of InputStream, not InputStreamReader.

Comment: I keep getting "File is empty" exception

Answer (score 37):

#### Simple Function

Try this simple function to neatly wrap it up in:

```
// Copy an InputStream to a File.
//
private void copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream in, File file) {
    OutputStream out = null;

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=in.read(buf))>0){
            out.write(buf,0,len);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        // Ensure that the InputStreams are closed even if there's an exception.
        try {
            if ( out != null ) {
                out.close();
            }

            // If you want to close the "in" InputStream yourself then remove this
            // from here but ensure that you close it yourself eventually.
            in.close();  
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*Thanks to Jordan LaPrise and his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18793899/293280).*

Comment: out.close() should be in a finally {} block to avoid leaking resources if an exception occurs.  Same for in.close() if it performed here, though it is really the responsibility of the caller to close it.

Comment: @jk7 You're probably right actually. Take a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 28):

**Kotlin** version (tested and no library needed):

```
fun copyStreamToFile(inputStream: InputStream, outputFile: File) {
    inputStream.use { input ->
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
        outputStream.use { output ->
            val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024) // buffer size
            while (true) {
                val byteCount = input.read(buffer)
                if (byteCount < 0) break
                output.write(buffer, 0, byteCount)
            }
            output.flush()
        }
    }
}
```

We take advantage of `use` function which will automatically close both streams at the end.

The streams are closed down correctly even in case an exception occurs.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/scoped-resource-usage.html

Comment: Sorry, what, if an exception oocurs (for instance, disconnection), can we rethrow the exception to an upper level?

Answer (score 8):

A shorter version:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(IOUtils.read(in));
out.close();
in.close();
```

Comment: because it requires IOUtils from Apache commons and that's a heavy weight dependency to add to a mobile app. Most people would rather a solution that relies on standard SDK classes.

Comment: For testing (`test` and `androidTest` artifacts), it's fine because it won't get included in app.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution which handles all the Exceptions and is based on the previous answers:

```
void writeStreamToFile(InputStream input, File file) {
    try {
        try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
            int read;
            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            output.flush();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. In your application's **`build.gradle`** file add under **`dependencies`**:

```
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
```

2. In your code:

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

// given you have a stream, e.g.
InputStream inputStream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

// you can now write it to a file with
FileUtils.copyToFile(inputStream, new File("myfile.txt"));
```

Comment: i put `implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5` ,synced, but it shows  `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;`'s FileUtils in red?

Answer (score 2):

There's the way of IOUtils:

```
copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
```

The code of it is similar to this :

```
public static long copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    long count = 0L;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
    for (int n; -1 != (n = input.read(buffer)); count += (long) n)
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more Kotlin-y approach:

```
fun copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream: InputStream, file: File) {
    try {
        inputStream.use { input ->
            FileOutputStream(file).use { input.copyTo(it) }
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

We use the `use` function for both the `inputStream` and the `FileOutputStream`. The use function ensures that the resources are closed properly after they are no longer needed, even in case of exceptions.

Additionally, we utilize the `copyTo` extension function available for InputStream, which simplifies the copying process and handles the buffering and loop logic internally. This makes the code more concise and reduces the chances of errors related to resource management.

Answer (score 0):

You can using [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)

```
 import com.google.common.io.ByteStreams;
```

Code:

```
 try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\example.txt"))){
      ByteStreams.copy(inputStream, fos)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern Kotlin way

```
fun File.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream: InputStream?) {
    outputStream().use { fileOut ->
        inputStream?.copyTo(fileOut)
    }
}

// Sample of usage
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        data?.data?.let { uri ->
            val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            val file = File(cacheDir, "todo_filename.jpg")
            file.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream)
        }
    }
```