# Copy contact photo to my folder

Tags: android-contacts, contactscontract

I get contact photo URI

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(contactID));
```

And I can now show this photo with Picaso:

```
Picasso.with(mainUserPhoto.getContext())
                    .load(uri)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.folder_placeholder)
                    .into(mainUserPhoto);
```

It is worked. But I need copy this image to my folder too. How can I copy this contact photo to my Folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`ContactsContract.Contacts`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) docs there's a convenience method called [`openContactPhotoInputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#openContactPhotoInputStream(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20boolean))

So you can do:

```
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(contactId));
InputStream is = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(), contactUri, true);
```

Se save an `InputStream` to a local file, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857407/819355

Comment: I know about this method and now I use it. I thought there was an opportunity get real PATH to contact photo....Just I have now 2 ways for save photo. 1 - from galary 2 - from contact(if exist). And When I pick photo from galary - I hold real path and after save I copy this photo to my app folder. But If I pick photo from contact now I hold InputStream and when save  - I cope InputStream to my app folder. I have 2 methods with params String(real path) and InputStream

Comment: there's no "real path" for contact pics, they are stored as blobs in the database itself, not on the device's filesystem

Comment: well, then I did the right thing. It just seemed like a bad approach. Thank you, your answer is in any case correct)