# Accessing JAR resources

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

I am having a lot of headache with creating .jar that loads resources. 
I read a lot of posts here, but I don't have an idea how should I use

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("..");
```

I need to load database into the memory:

```
File file = new File(Thread.currentThread().
getContextClassLoader().getResource("phonebook").getFile());                          
String attachStmt = "ATTACH '" + file + "' AS tempInMemoryDb";
stmt.execute(attachStmt);
```

So if I run project from NetBeans it loads database just fine, but when I do clean and build, and run jar file from dis folder I see in command line that phonebook file (database file) isn't loaded. So, my question is: how should I use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("..")` to create file and pass it to `"String attachStmt = "ATTACH '" + file + "' AS tempInMemoryDb";` so I can load DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ATTACH` expects a file as input, but when you build a JAR for your application, the file you are referring to is inside this JAR and not extracted! In this case, you need to write the data to a file first.

Create an empty temporary file by calling [`File.createTemporaryFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). The use one of the methods described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43157/335858) to copy the content of the stream returned from `getResourceAsStream` into the temporary file.

When you program exits, don't forget to delete the temporary file. One way to ensure that is to call [`deleteOnExit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29) on the temporary file object returned in the first step.