# read flat file from junit test

Tags: java, file, junit

I am trying to set up a junit test that reads a pdf file to pass into my method, which takes a File parameters. The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to find the pdf file.

I need this to work both inside of eclipse as a single test and once the test has been zipped into a jar file for our automated build.

For simplicity, I've put the postcard.pdf right next to the junit test class. Here's the last thing I've tried.

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("postcard.pdf");
URI uri = url.toURI();
File file = new File(uri);
javamailService.sendMessage(MAILUSER, REPLY_TO, SUBJECT, file, MimeType.pdf);
fail("Not yet implemented");
```

Help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just coding a relative path. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I only have to change the path such that it works for test data:

```
File file = new File("./testdata/pdftest/test.pdf");
```

But if in your case that would not work, then "mock" out the file by defining a `IFileProvider` interface.

```
public interface IFileProvider {
  File getFile(URI uri);
}
```

in junit test use a

```
class DummyPdfFileProvider implements IFileProvider {
    File getFile(URI uri) {
       // ignore uri
       return new File("./testdata/test.pdf");
    }
}
```

In Real code use a

```
class PdfFileProvider implements IFileProvider {
    File getFile(URI uri) {
       // ignore uri
       return new File(uri);
    }
}
```

Change now real code to use the `PdfFileProvider`

```
IFileProvider fileProvider = new PdfFileProvider();

URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("postcard.pdf");
URI uri = url.toURI();
File file = fileProvider.getFile(uri);
javamailService.sendMessage(MAILUSER, REPLY_TO, SUBJECT, file, MimeType.pdf);
// and remove the fail below:
//fail("Not yet implemented");
```

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem, although I appreciate the info. All I need to do is create a file. I just can't seem to get the File without hard coding the absolute path that will break on our test server and on other's workstations.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code, by keeping test.pdf at the root level. And Java Mails Service API supports to add attachment as InputStream/InputStreamSource.

```
InputStream configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could include the file (postcard.pdf) in classpath-- by adding to a jar and add that to classpath.   Then get the file using [getAsResourceStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.ht) and write [stream to a temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream).