# Opening an image file from java InputStream

Tags: java, image, inputstream, javax.imageio

I am trying to open an image file that is packaged in a .jar file using the default image viewer of the computer on which i run my program.

I have found numerous answers about how to access files that are packaged in a jar using InputStream but how can i open those files using that InputStream?

```
InputStream imageStream = Test.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test/DSC_6283.jpg");
```

I can convert this into an `Image`, `ImageIcon` or a `BufferedImage` but how to i further open the image in the default image viewer?

My class name is 'Test' and the image i am trying to access is `C:\Users\Pranav\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Test\src\test\DSC_6283.jpg`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pure java:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    InputStream imageStream = Test.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test/DSC_6283.jpg");
    Path path = Files.createTempFile("DSC_6283", ".jpg");
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path.toFile())) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
        int len; 
        while ((len = imageStream.read(buffer)) != -1) { 
            out.write(buffer, 0, len); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(path.toFile());
}
```

---

Edit:

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //allocate an array of bytes to use as a buffer. 1024 bytes in this case
        int len; //a variable to record the number of bytes actually read from the stream each loop
        while ((len = imageStream.read(buffer)) != -1) { //InputStream.read(byte[]) reads bytes from the stream and places them into the buffer. It returns the number of bytes placed into the buffer, or -1 if there is nothing more to read. We store that result in len, and evaluate if we should stop looping (ie if the return is -1)
            out.write(buffer, 0, len); //write to the output file, from the buffer, starting at position 0, through the number of bytes read
```

Note, this is boilerplate. I stole this version from [Easy way to write contents of a Java InputStream to an OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream)

Comment: Thanks a lot!:) Works perfectly! Could you please explain how these lines work- 

`byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];`

`int len;`
`while ((len = imageStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {`
`out.write(buffer, 0, len);`
`}`

Comment: @Pranav added comments

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the image locally (ex. c:\my_image.jpg), which is not in the .jar file
2. Use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd your_command_here_to_open_image");`
   here is a link for cmd command on windows: http://www.sevenforums.com/software/180378-where-windows-photo-viewer-default-location.html

Comment: probably the temp folder would be more appropriate than C:\