# how to convert buffer reader into bitmap

Tags: java, android, xml

```
 connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
 connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", mCookiesList.get(0) + ";" + mCookiesList.get(1));
 connection.connect();
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

`

Comment: in the bufferreader image view is coming but how to take that image view from buffer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening an image file from java InputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669874/opening-an-image-file-from-java-inputstream)

Comment: Further to that, `BufferedReader` is for reading text files.  An image is a binary file, so that class would not be an appropriate choice.

Comment: so what to do to get an image file  i m passing a url  its getting imageview so how do i get it

Comment: Answer is in the duplicate.

Comment: you have `connection.getInputStream()` so use it directly for `Bitmap` decoding (by means of `BitmapFactory` class)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javax.imageio.ImageIO class to construct a BufferedImage having an InputStream :

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(connection.getInputStream());
```

Then, if you are going to write is to disk as a bitmap :

```
int imageWithInPixels = 200;
int imageHeightInPixels = 200;
BufferedImage bitmapImage = new BufferedImage(imageWithInPixels , imageHeightInPixels , BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
bitmapImage.getGraphics().drawImage(
    bufferedImage , 0, 0, imageWithInPixels , imageHeightInPixels , null);
ImageIO.write(bitmapImage , "BMP", new File("filename.bmp"));
```