# How to upload and download file to hdfs using Java code

Tags: java, hadoop

i am newbie to hadoop, and trying to upload and download files to hdfs via. Java code. which should behave as

Data Uploading:

```
 hadoop fs -put or -copyFromLocal filename directoryName
```

and Data Downloading

```
  hadoop fs -get or -copyToLocal filename directoryName
```

from hdfs. i need this one because datasets contain image, audio, video etc file. above command works fine with all type of data, if i try using Java i/o reader code , it is working fine for text files , but not for images, video. docx etc..

pls any help here.

**Edited Here:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        Path path=new Path("data");
        Path file=new Path(path,"screenshots.png");

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/hduser/Desktop/screenshots.png"));
        if (!fs.exists(path))
          throw new IOException("Output not found!");

        ImageIO.write(image, "png", fs.open(path));


    }
```

As asked i have edited here code that i am using to upload image file to hdfs. here `ImageIO.write` is not accepting arguement `fs.open(path)` , because is asking for file, but i have to give path here as to read and to write to hdfs we need to give path only. Actually i am in need of a method to upload and download file from hdfs using code for all type of data, so i should not write code and use plugins for all type of file.

Comment: Please show the code that you're trying to use and tell us exactly why you think it doesn't work.

Comment: if you are familiar Spring then you can use [Spring Hadoop](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hadoop/), you can [see sample example here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples/tree/master/mapreduce) which will move the input files into hdfs using groovy file and runs your Map-Reduce as a job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageIO.write can take an OutputStream as well as a File.  However, fs.open is returning an InputStream because it is for reading files only.

You need to call:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", fs.create(file));
```

The create method will return an `OutputStream` which ImageIO can write to.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html

Comment: Hi Paolo, it works.. can you please tell, what should i use to upload all types of file to hdfs and download from hdfs, without writing code for all types of file format.  +1

Comment: Just open whatever file you want using the standard Java FileInputStream, read it and write the output to your HDFS outputstream.  This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream

Answer (score 0):

1. If `path` is already exists than you will overwrite that file with your image. I think that you want to save your image into some existing folder in `HDFS`. In that case you need to write your image to `new Path(path, "SomeImageName.png");`.
2. You don't need to use `ImageIO` to copy the image from local file system to `HDFS`. Try to use `copyFromLocalFile` method of `FileSystem`:

   fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("/home/hduser/Desktop/screenshots.png"), path);