# Uploading Image to Server to be downloaded by iOS

Tags: java, ios, image, server, uploading

I am attempting to upload an image to my server in java and then download it in iOS within an app. When I upload / download with java, it works, but when I download it in iOS the image just turns up black. Also, when I view the image in browser it has a purple hue over it convincing me that the image is corrupt. Am I not uploading the image correctly?

Code:

public void uploadToServer() {

```
    String server = "ip";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "name";
    String pass = "pass";

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int w = 765;
        int h = 503;
        double d = .85;
        BufferedImage img = resize(client.methods.getClientImage(),
                (int) (w * d), (int) (h * d));

        ImageIO.write(img, "JPG", os);
        InputStream inputStream = new     ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());

        String secondRemoteFile = "directory";

        // System.out.println("Start uploading file");
        OutputStream outputStream = ftpClient
                .storeFileStream(secondRemoteFile);

        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[4096];
        int read = 0;

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        ftpClient.completePendingCommand();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Heres the purple tint:
[image]

iOS Code:

```
- (void) refreshImage {
 client.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:    [NSURL   URLWithString:@"http://link.jpg"]]]; ;
}
```

Comment: This code looks good. Try to download image manually from server and verify. You can simplify by following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream

Comment: It does indeed work when being downloaded within another java application, it does not work within an iOS application though.

Comment: Where's the iOS code?

Comment: Then it is iOS code issue, please provide those

Comment: Ok I posted iOS code, and I've also discovered that it works if I use a PNG file instead of JPG but I need to use JPG for it is compressed more efficiently and I need to download the image as fast as possible.

Comment: The problem might be what you do before uploading the file onto a FTP server. Your image compression method code in Java might not be compatible with iOS or just doesn't work as expected. Please try to remove image compression code around "BufferedImage img = resize(client.methods.getClientImage(),
                (int) (w * d), (int) (h * d)); ImageIO.write(img, "JPG", os);" and directly verify the image by downloading the file with FTP in a desktop browser or Safari on iPhone without your iOS app.

Comment: I tried it without the resize and got the same result