# Access image file inside a Jar file dynamically

Tags: java, html, jar

I have a Java project,exported as a JAR file (Desktop Application) which generates a HTML file as output. The output html file, needs to read one image file, as the page's logo. The JAR application will be in say X folder. The target html file will be placed dynamically anywhere. How do I make the html,residing in someother location, access the image, inside the JAR file.

In short, how do I determine the path for the below code, for the above scenario.

```
java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("image.jpg");
fw.write("<tr><td><b>"+csname+"</b></td><td> <img src = "+url.toString()+"'>/td></tr>");
```

works fine, when i run in eclipse. But not when exported as JAR
The resultant html file,in some other folder has the code

```
<img src="rsrc:com/demo/dirapitoword/image.jpg">
```

Comment: Isn't the HTML written by the same JAR the image is in?

Comment: Yes, the JAR generetes the HTML, using fw.write()

Comment: Then post your attempt at reading the image inside one of your classes.

Comment: java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("image.jpg");

fw.write("<tr><td><b>"+csname+"</b></td><td> <img src = '"+url.toString()+"'></td></tr>");

works fine, when i run in eclipse. But not when exported as JAR
The resultant html file,in some other folder has the code

<img src="rsrc:com/demo/dirapitoword/image.jpg">

Comment: Edit your answer and put the code in a code block. Don't post code in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [read the image as a stream from the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java), e.g.:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("image.jpg");
```

and write the stream out as a file to a known place on disk. There are [lots of ways to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream), if you're using Java 7 or above, try:

```
File out = new File("image.jpg");
Files.copy(in, out.toPath());
```

Then, your `src` attribute can use the relative location you chose to display this image in the HTML, without having to worry about Jar compatibility in the browser / client.

Answer (score 0):

You can find that the `jar:` URI Scheme exist for .zip containers as described in the Wikipedia here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

The format is:

```
jar:<url>!/[<entry>]
```

*BUT* it is not supported by all browsers (only Firefox actually) as described in this article: https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part1

Even in that case, I think it is not very nice that the output .html can be elsewhere but contains an absolute path to your resources.

I suggest to use the `data:` URI scheme which allows to embed the image within the HTML page.

There is a question that covers this procedure: [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

And in one of the answers, there is an interesting fiddle sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/hpP45/