# bitmap.compress from Uri resulting in OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am trying to save a bitmap which user selects into my own App path.

Unfortunately, with very big images I get OutOfMemoryError error.

I am using the following code:

```
private String loadImage (Uri filePath) {
    File fOut = new File(getFilesDir(),"own.jpg");

    inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(filePath);
    selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);

    selectedImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(fOut));
}
```

Is there any way for me to save any image file of any size for an Uri to a file?

*I am not in a position to resize the image e.g. by using calculateInSampleSize method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way for me to save any image file of any size for an Uri to a file?

Since it already is an image, just copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream`:

```
private void copyInputStreamToFile( InputStream in, File file ) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int len;

        while((len=in.read(buf))>0){
            out.write(buf,0,len);
        }

        out.flush();
        out.getFD().sync();
        out.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18793899/115145))

Comment: This does not work for me ... no errors, just no file!  My Uri (filePath) is pointing to a local file.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @user1148358: Step through your code using a debugger. If the code is writing lots of bytes out to your desired `File`, then clearly the file exists.