# How to add up two InputStream object

Tags: java, android

I want to add up two `InputStream` objects that actually are a splitted .JPG file into one and then use it in a `Drawable` to show in ImageView. I googled and found `SequenceInputStream` but it didn't work.the code is blow:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;

import android.R.drawable;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoadFromAssetsActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView mImage;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_from_assets);

        mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        loadDataFromAsset();
    }

        public void loadDataFromAsset() {


        // load image
        try {
            // get input stream
            InputStream ims1 = getAssets().open("1");
            InputStream ims2 = getAssets().open("2");
            InputStream imsTotal = new SequenceInputStream(ims1, ims2);



            // load image as Drawable
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(imsTotal, null);


            // set image to ImageView
            mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? try save the `imsTotal ` into a file and see if the image data is correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18793899/971070

Comment: I did what your link said. but how to check the content of that `file`. I'm beginner in android

Comment: `File file = new File("/sdcard/1.jpg");`, then find it on the sdcard. Make sure you have this permission to write file to sdcard: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: it's empty!!! what did wrong in my code? when in windows copy `2` content after `1` content and save as .jpg it shows the image!

Comment: I also use your method to save only`ims1` (file  `1` ) content but it's empty too!!