# Adding buffer when writing byte[] to OutputStream

Tags: java, buffer

In my method, I'm saving data from file to an output stream.

For now, it looks like this

```
public void readFileToOutputStream(Path path, OutputStream os) {
    byte[] barr = Files.readAllBytes(path)

    os.write(barr);
    os.flush();
}
```

But in this solution, all bytes are loaded into memory, and I want to use buffer to release some of it.

What can I use to supply my reading with buffer?

Comment: Take a look at this answer in the linked question:http://stackoverflow.com/a/19194580/1743880 There is a built-in for that: `Files.copy(Path, OutputStream)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. easist way is to use [Commons IO library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

   ```
   public void readFileToOutputStream(Path path, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
     try(InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path.toFile())){
       IOUtils.copy(in, os);
     }
   }
   ```
2. You can implement on your own similar to *IOUtils.copy*

   ```
   public void readFileToOutputStream(Path path, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
     try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path.toFile());
          InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {
       byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
       int n;
       while ((n = bis.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
         os.write(buffer, 0, n);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right, you would like to only write a specified amount of bytes to memory?

outputstreams write method can also write a specified byte array from a starting offset and length.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html

```
public void readFileToOutputStream(Path path, OutputStream os, int off, int len) {
    byte[] barr = Files.readAllBytes(path)

    os.write(barr, off, len);
    os.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use buffered streams to manage the buffer for you:

```
public void readFileToOutputStream(Path path, OutputStream os) {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path.toFile())) {
        try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {
            try (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis)) {
                try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os)) {
                    try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos)) {
                        try {
                            while (true) {
                                dos.writeByte(dis.readByte());
                            }
                        } catch (EOFException e) {
                            // normal behaviour
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have multiple resources inside the `try` part instead of nesting as many try blocks as resources.

Comment: @Tunaki didn't know that.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileInputStream::read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int))
to read up to `len` bytes to buffer `b` and `FileOutputStream::write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` [link2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(byte[])) to write from buffer