# copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out)

Tags: java, android

I have read through the [Security with HTTPS and SSL](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#java) documentation from Android. I see that it keeps using `copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out);`. That gives me

`error: cannot find symbol method copyInputStreamToOutputStream(InputStream,PrintStream)`

Here's the code in question:

```
URL url = new URL("https://wikipedia.org");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out);
```

What is the meaning of `copyInputStreamToOutputStream`?

Comment: Looks like a method to copy an input stream to an output stream to me. They don't seem to provide it but it's only six lines of code or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Easy way to write contents of a Java InputStream to an OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream)

> org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils from Apache has a method called
>   copy(InputStream,OutputStream) which does exactly what you're looking
>   for.
>
> IOUtils.copy(in,out);