# Why is the example from developer.android not working

Tags: android, ssl, url

I'm about to code an Android app (using A.Studio 3.5.1) that should connect to a back-end using https. I'm quite new to the techniques so I looked at https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#HttpsExample

I has four lines of code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://wikipedia.org");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out);
```

When I try it I get a red text;

new URL gives MalformedURLException
url.openConnection() gives IOException,

urlConnection.getInputStream() also

copyInputStreamToOutputStream is not found.

I have read about copyInputStreamToOutputStream, that it can be solved

[copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886808/copyinputstreamtooutputstreamin-system-out)

and

[Easy way to write contents of a Java InputStream to an OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream)

I tried the first way, using apache commons, with no success.

I'm mostly curious about the exceptions.

I will try another walk-through on

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-network-security-config/

But it would be nice to learn about this...

Comment: I suggest using Retrofit instead for consuming Rest APIs https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @StanislavShamilov - yes

Comment: @Zun - yes, Retrofit seems to be a good idea! I looked at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JGvDUlfk7Y and now the app (another app) can fetch json. It works on my Android 5.1 phone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar situations many times. This occur because the webpage you are trying to reach doesn't return anything as a response after connection is established. So the parsing returns IOException as there is nothing to read in the response of URL after connection. 
newURL is returning MalformedURLException because your url contains -- " -- which should be escaped as these are special characters.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but these "exceptions" comes before even running the program, so I'm sure the url hasn't even been visited.