# Can't change LatLng of an image using ExifInterface object, via URI on Nougat

Tags: android, uri

I am desiging an android program to change LatLng of images. Images Uri is in an Array  the code is as follows

Exception that occurs says 
`"ExifInterface does not support saving attributes for the currrent input"`

```
    InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream((Uri)AddArray[i]);

    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(in);

    ei.setAttribute(TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, "80/1,35/1,4091/100");
    ei.setAttribute(TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "N");
    ei.setAttribute(TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, "45/1,1/1,4390/100");
    ei.setAttribute(TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "E");



    try {
        ei.saveAttributes();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExifInterface`, as you are using it, only has an `InputStream`, and so it has no way of persisting your changes.

You would need to:

- Use the `InputStream` to make a copy of the content identified by that `Uri` to some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`)
- Use `ExifInterface` with that file, saving changes to that file
- Use `openOutputStream()` on `ContentResolver` to get an `OutputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`, then copy the bytes of the file to that `OutputStream`

Comment: can u please elaborate this line:

Use the InputStream to make a copy of the content identified by that Uri to some file that you control (e.g., in getCacheDir())

Comment: @AbdullahMufti: `InputStream` is part of `java.io`. You use it to read in data from some source (file, HTTP response, etc.). You can create a `FileOutputStream` on some file that you control, and use standard Java I/O to copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`. When you are done, you have a file that contains the same data as whatever the `Uri` points to. Now, you can use `ExifInterface` with that file, and `ExifInterface` can save to the file.

Comment: One Last Favor : Can u please identify the mistake in my code
        InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream((Uri)AddArray[i]);

        File myFile=getCacheDir();
        File outFile=new File(myFile, String.valueOf(in));
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outFile.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: @AbdullahMufti: I do not know why you are trying to name your file something like `InputStream@f384d304`, which is what I would expect `String.valueOf(in)` to return. You can pass the `File` directly to `new FileOutputStream()` without the `getAbsolutePath()`. And you have no code here to copy data between the streams. Java I/O is covered in many books and courses on Java programming. Or, search `java copy input stream to outputstream` in your favorite search engine for solutions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40019374/115145).