# MVStore Online Back Up

Tags: h2

The [information](http://javadox.com/com.h2database/h2/1.4.182/org/h2/mvstore/MVStore.html#setReuseSpace(boolean)) in the MVStore docs on backing up a database is a little vague, and I'm not familiar with all the concepts and terminology, so I wanted to see if the approach I came up with makes sense.

I'm a Clojure programmer, so please forgive my Java here:

```java
// db is an MVStore instance
FileStore fs = db.getFileStore();
FileOutputStream fos = java.io.FileOutputStream(pathToBackupFile);
FileChannel outChannel = fos.getChannel();
try {
  db.commit();
  db.setReuseSpace(false);
  ByteBuffer bb = fs.readFully(0, fs.size());
  outChannel.write(bb);
}
finally {
  outChannel.close();
  db.setReuseSpace(true);
}
```

Here's what it looks like in Clojure in case my Java is bad:

```clj
(defn backup-db
  [db path-to-backup-file]
  (let [fs (.getFileStore db)
        backup-file (java.io.FileOutputStream. path-to-backup-file)
        out-channel (.getChannel backup-file)]
    (try
      (.commit db)
      (.setReuseSpace db false)
      (let [file-contents (.readFully fs 0 (.size fs))]
        (.write out-channel file-contents))
      (finally
        (.close out-channel)
        (.setReuseSpace db true)))))
```

My approach seems to work, but I wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything or see if there's a better way.  Thanks!

P.S. I used the H2 tag because MVStore doesn't exist and I don't have enough reputation to create it.

Comment: i have created the tag for you

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://www.h2database.com/html/mvstore.html#fileSystem) currently say:

> The persisted data can be backed up at any time, even during write
>   operations (online backup). To do that, automatic disk space reuse
>   needs to be first disabled, so that new data is always appended at the
>   end of the file. Then, the file can be copied. The file handle is
>   available to the application. It is recommended to use the utility
>   class FileChannelInputStream to do this.

The classes `FileChannelInputStream` and `FileChannelOutputStream` convert a `java.nio.FileChannel` into a standard InputStream and OutputStream. There is existing H2 code in [BackupCommand.java](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/393c7b151075b0812776c8b72b5ed5873c64a05c/h2/src/main/org/h2/command/dml/BackupCommand.java#L92) that shows how to use them. We can improve upon it using Java 9 [input.transferTo(output);](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39440936/329496) to copy the data:

```java
    public void backup(MVStore s, File backupFile) throws Exception {
        try {
            s.commit();
            s.setReuseSpace(false);
            try(RandomAccessFile outFile = new java.io.RandomAccessFile(backupFile, "rw");
                FileChannelOutputStream output = new FileChannelOutputStream(outFile.getChannel(), false)){
                    try(FileChannelInputStream input = new FileChannelInputStream(s.getFileStore().getFile(), false)){
                        input.transferTo(output);
                    }
            }
        } finally {
            s.setReuseSpace(true);
        }
    }
```

Note that when you create the `FileChannelInputStream` you have to pass `false` to tell it to not close the underlying file channel when the stream is closed. If you don't do that it will close the file that your `FileStore` is trying to use. That code uses try-with-resource syntax to make sure that the output file is properly closed.

In order to try this, I checked out the mvstore code then modified the [TestMVStore](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/test/org/h2/test/store/TestMVStore.java) to add a `testBackup()` method which is similar to the existing  `testSimple()` code:

```java
    private void testBackup() throws Exception {
        // write some records like testSimple
        String fileName = getBaseDir() + "/" + getTestName();
        FileUtils.delete(fileName);
        MVStore s = openStore(fileName);
        MVMap<Integer, String> m = s.openMap("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            m.put(i, "hello " + i);
        }

        // create a backup
        String fileNameBackup = getBaseDir() + "/" + getTestName() + ".backup";
        FileUtils.delete(fileNameBackup);
        backup(s, new File(fileNameBackup));

        // this throws if you accidentally close the input channel you get from the store
        s.close();

        // open the backup and verify
        s = openStore(fileNameBackup);
        m = s.openMap("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            assertEquals("hello " + i, m.get(i));
        }
        s.close();
    }
```

With your example, you are reading into a `ByteBuffer` which must fit into memory. Using the stream `transferTo` method uses an internal buffer that is currently (as at Java11) set to 8192 bytes.