# Fastest way to read from InputStream to OutputStream

Tags: java

This code below streams at *1.3 seconds* for a *2.43 MB* file

```
byte[] buff = new byte[64*1024];

private static void flow(InputStream is, OutputStream os, byte[] buf )
        throws IOException {
    int numRead;
    while ( (numRead = is.read(buf) ) >= 0) {
        os.write(buf, 0, numRead);
    }
}
```

What is the fastest way to "stream" an `InputStream` to `OutputStream`?

**Update:**

Data source is a cache, EHCache to be specific:

```
byte[] cached = cacheService.get(cacheKey); // Just `2 ms` to get the bytes, very fast
if(cached != null && cached.length > 0) {
    flow(ByteSource.wrap(cached).openStream(), outputStream, buff);
}
```

Comment: That's it, you've already found it. The loop condition should be `>`. You can only get zero if the buffer length is zero, which it isn't, and if it was you wouldn't want to loop forever. I don't see the point of the third parameter. The buffer should be a local variable, not a class member, for thread-safety.

Comment: But if you already have the data in a byte array, why are you using an `InputStream` and another method call at all? Just call `OutputStream.write()` directly with the byte array you already have. Anything else is just a waste of time and space.

Answer (score 2):

I can't make any assertion that it's the fastest but I would suggest using `apache-commons-io`'s `IOUtils`. Specifically

```
public static long copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output, int bufferSize)
```

and try to benchmark with different values of `bufferSize`.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20int)

The real problem here is the high level of abstraction you're working with. Provided you know exactly where the data is coming from (e.g. the file system) and where it's going (e.g network socket) and you know which operating system you're working on, it is possible to leverage the kernel's stream support to make this much faster.

Googling for "zero copy kernel io" I found this article which is an okay overview:
https://xunnanxu.github.io/2016/09/10/It-s-all-about-buffers-zero-copy-mmap-and-Java-NIO/

Comment: Data is coming from EHCache (Teracotta) which is from my benchmark reads that same file in few `ms`.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 9, InputStream provides a **transferTo(OutStream)** method or using [Java 7 Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) can also be used.
Again no claims on which is the fastest but you can benchmark these as well.

References:

1. [Official Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-)
2. [A similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream)

Answer (score 1):

I would also have said commons-io: [IOUtils::copy](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) which does this probably better than a naive approach, but the code seems to do the same as yours (see [copyLarge](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java#L1123)) but answer about Java 9 makes it a better choice.

```
public static long copyLarge(final InputStream input, final OutputStream output, final byte[] buffer)
        throws IOException {
    long count = 0;
    int n;
    while (EOF != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }
    return count;
}
```

However, your problem may not be how you copy, but rather the lack of buffering: you could try with `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` on top of existing stream:

- `Files.newInputStream` is not buffered.
- `Files.newOutputStream` is not buffered.
- You could use `FileChannel` and `ByteBuffer`.
- System is probably buffering file on its side.

You should roll up a JMH benchmark test:

- Not sure how you can disable system buffering. I don't think it is a problem.
- I would first check result with buffered input stream of various size (8K, 16K, 32K, 64K, 512K, 1M, 2M, 4M, 8M)
- Then with buffered output stream
- Then with a mix of two.

While it may take time to execute, the road to *what the fastest* implies measuring.

Comment: Not actually dealing with files but rather cached data. I have updated the original post where I have posted the use of the method after getting the byte arrays from the cache; the cache is very fast. Just few milliseconds to get the 2.43 MB, 2 ms to be exact.

Comment: Then you have to test the OutputStream.