# Write from one OutputStream to another InputStream

Tags: java, input, output

I want to have an `InputStream` in a class like this:

```
class A {

    InputStream inputStream = ...

}
```

And I want to write to that `InputStream` using a `OutputStream` from another class which is in the same application. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Take a Look at PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream

Comment: THere's an answer here that looks relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is! `PipedOutputStream` ([see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html)) and a `PipedInputStream` ([see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html)) is what you need.

Here is a little example how to use it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
    PipedInputStream inputStream = new PipedInputStream();
    PipedOutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream(inputStream);

    // Write some data to the output stream
    writeDataToOutputStream(outputStream);

    // Now read that data
    Scanner src = new Scanner(inputStream);

    System.out.println(src.nextLine());
}

private static void writeDataToOutputStream(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write("Hello!\n".getBytes());
}
```

The code will output:

```
Hello!
```